# InternetExplorer.Application ReadyState is always blank

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation

I have this very simple snippet from my script:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate("https://10.0.0.1/ccmadmin/phoneFindList.do")
while ($ie.readyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100; Write-Host $ie.readyState }
```

I have definitely used very similar code before with no issues, however for some reason when I run this script, `$ie.readyState` just contains a blank value, and so prints an empty string to the console, and it never gets set to `4` (or anything else for that matter.

I can see that the page has a cert error, but I'm pretty sure this should still work.

What could possibly cause this issue?

When stepping through the script, I can see that `readyState` contains a value of 0 all the way up til line 3, where we call `navigate` - at this point `readyState` is set to an empty string or blank...

Comment: Why are you pretty sure it should still work?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Based on examples of code I have seen which does the same as above before circumventing the cert issue (by sending `click` to the continue to page link), and also the fact that this was working yesterday (at least the script was getting past that stage).

Comment: I just tested your post, pointed to one of my sites and get the expect output. 1
1
1
1
1
3
4 ... I also hit a couple of other public sites and 4 was reached each time.

Comment: @postanote I have used this code may times before, so I know it does work. My question is more about why it might not be working in my case, or what options do I have to try to debug this annoying issue?

Comment: Yours seems like and environment issue vs a PoSH one. Because when I run your block with your site, I get 1 4. As for troubleshooting, I would fire up fiddler and see what your site is kicking back as responses or trying on another machine. I'd also measure this to check response times or even set a debugger to attach to the IE process and review what that spits out.

Comment: @postanote Thanks for your comment - I appear to have found a workaround (removing s from https), but I just dont get this. Also now when I call `getelementbyid` on the `$ie.document`, I am seeing `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A138A`

Answer (score 0):

When you look at all the API info on the underlying IHTMLXMLHttp* info on MSDN and W3C sites, there is no indication of SSL restriction in use. Do a trace on the request and see property it is getting hung on.

```
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED (0)

The object has been created, but not initialized (the IHTMLXMLHttpRequest::open method has not been called).

READYSTATE_LOADING (1)

A request has been opened, but the IHTMLXMLHttpRequest::send method has not been called. 

READYSTATE_LOADED (2)

The IHTMLXMLHttpRequest::send method has been called. No data is available yet. 

READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE (3)

Some data has been received; however, IHTMLXMLHttpRequest::responseText is not available. 

READYSTATE_COMPLETE (4)

All the data has been received.
```

Comment: Hi postanote I don't know what you mean by that. Also, what does it mean if `readyState` returns an empty string after first returning 0 for a few milliseconds? This makes no sense...